# Unable to access Angular2 Service object properties

Tags: angular, service

I followed the Angular2 documentation to create a service for my app, but I cannot seem to access the information on the front end.

When I try to access `firstVariable` and `secondVariable` in the template using interpolation, I get `[Object object]`.  I decided to use the json pipe to get a nice read out of the object, which works.  However, I can't figure out why I cannot access `firstVariable` and `secondVariable`.  I get an error that reads `cannot read property 'firstVariable' of undefined`.

Here is my code:

**moose.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import { MooseService } from './moose.service';

import { MooseCode } from './moose.code';


@Component({
  selector: 'moose-selector',
  templateUrl: './moose.component.html',
  providers: [MooseService]
})

export class MooseComponent implements OnInit {

  currentThing: MooseCode[];

  getCode(): void {
    this._mooseService.getCodeSlowly()
    .then(currentThing => this.currentThing = currentThing);
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getCode();
  }

  constructor(private _mooseService: MooseService) {}

}
```

**moose.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

import { MooseCode } from './moose.code';
import { MOCK_DATA } from './mock-data';

@Injectable()

export class MooseService {

  getCode(): Promise<MooseCode[]> {
    return Promise.resolve(MOCK_DATA);
  }

  getCodeSlowly(): Promise<MooseCode[]> {
    return new Promise<MooseCode[]>(resolve =>
      setTimeout(resolve, 2000)) // delay 2 seconds
      .then(() => this.getCode());
  }

}
```

**moose.component.html**

```
<pre>
{{ currentThing | json }}
</pre>
```

**moose.code.ts**

```
export class MooseCode {

  constructor(
    public firstVariable: any,
    public secondVariable: any,
  ) {}
}
```

**mock.data.ts**

```
import { MooseCode } from './moose.code';

export const MOCK_DATA: MooseCode[] = [
  {
      'firstVariable': 'any',
      'secondVariable': 'any',
}
];
```

I tried accessing `firstVariable` and `secondVariable` in the template using the following methods:

`{{currentThing.firstVariable}}`
and
`{{currentThing[0].firstVariable}}`

Nothing works! What am I doing wrong?

Comment: can you also include the contents of mock-data.ts

Comment: @John, I added the mock.data.ts file for you to inspect!

Comment: At some point `currentThing` is undefined. This means that its properties should be accessed as `{{currentThing?[0].firstVariable}}` or so.

Comment: @John, I tried your suggestion and did not get the value for firstVariable to show.

Answer (score 0):

Your services' `getHomePageCodeSlowly` resolves with no value. Try:

```
setTimeout(resolve(MOCK_DATA), 2000))
```

then @ component `getCode()` currentThing[0].firstVariable or secondvariable

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo. It should say `getCodeSlowly`

Comment: It has the same result, there is no output on the front end.

Comment: don't inherit from `moose.code` @ `mock.data` and see if it works

Comment: by removing `MooseCode[]` from the expression. Try this too @ `moose.code.ts`:

    export class EditorsChoiceCode {
        public firstVariable: any;
        public secondVariable: any;
    
      constructor() {}
    }

Were you trying to use moose.code.ts as an interface/model to define your MOCK_DATA? if so https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html might be better ?

Comment: sorry for the additional typo, i changed it to MooseCode from EditorsChoiceCode

Comment: I dont _think_ i need to use an interface.

Comment: hmmm, could it be because `getCode()` @moose.component.ts returns void ?

Answer (score 0):

@estus approach will work - `{{currentThing?[0].firstVariable}}`. But if you don't want to use a question mark each time, use an ngIf - this will work the same way. so for instance, assuming:

```
ItemObject = {
  id: 1,
  name: "something",
  anotherProperty: "whatever",
  isThisReal: false
}
<div class="item" *ngIf="ItemsObject">
  <h1>{{ItemObject.isThisReal}}</h1>
</div>
```

The output should be: `<h1>false</h1>`